# batch file blank variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename the contents of a folder based on it's name and adding an alphabet at the end. But I'm having a hard time getting the letter based on my defined array of alphabets. Here's my code so far.

```
@echo off

set letters[1]=a
set letters[2]=b
set letters[3]=c
set letters[4]=d
set letters[5]=e
set letters[6]=f
set letters[7]=g
set letters[8]=h
set letters[9]=i
set letters[10]=j
set letters[11]=k
set letters[12]=l
set letters[13]=m
set letters[14]=n
set letters[15]=o
set letters[16]=p
set letters[17]=q
set letters[18]=r
set letters[19]=s
set letters[20]=t
set letters[21]=u
set letters[22]=v
set letters[23]=w
set letters[24]=x
set letters[25]=y
set letters[26]=z

set /a index=0

pushd %1

for %%a in (%1) do set folder=%%~na

echo renaming %folder%...

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.*) do (
    set /a index+=1
    set suffix=!letters[%index%]!
    echo appending -!suffix!...
    ren "%%~fi" "%folder%-!suffix!.*"
)
endlocal

popd

pause
exit /b
```

I have read that using the EnableDelayedExpansion helps in these kinds of situation also the use of (!) for the delayed variable? I'm still pretty new at this, I don't know where am I going wrong with this or how I can create a work around for this. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider adding details about the task to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
set suffix=!letters[%index%]!
```

with

```
CALL set suffix=%%letters[!index!]%%
```

`%index%` refers to the value of `index` at the time the `for %%i` is parsed, not as it changes through the operation of the loop.

Note that you'll run out of suffixes if you have more than 26 targets!

(btw - `for %%a in (%1) do set folder=%%~na` is probably better-off as `set folder=%%~n1` )